# GroupBy using two conditions in scala

Tags: scala

I have `List[(Int,Int)]`

For ex.

```
val a= List((1,2), (3,4), (1,3), (4,2), (5,4), (3,8))
```

I want to perform operation like this:

Take first element and groupby using below condition:

1. If first tuple of the element is in remaining elements' first tuple then include it

or

2. If first tuple of the element is in remaining elements' first tuple then include it

Then skip that tuples which are included and for remaining tuple do the same  process.
Possible Answer:

```
 val ans= Map((1,2)->List((1,2),(1,3),(4,2)), (3,4)->List(3,4),(5,4),(3,8))
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I think you have `tuple` and `element` confused in your description. And your two conditions are identical!  So, I can't work out how to get from your description to the answer. Have another go?

Comment: No I am considering (1,2) as `element` of List and 1 as `first tuple` of that element and 2 as `second tuple`. Two conditions are identical but `or` operation between them

Comment: That is wrong, (1,2) is a tuple(tuple2 actually) and it is an element of List

Comment: If the two conditions are identical, the `or` adds nothing. Please do take note of what I am saying - your usage of `tuple` is wrong, and your question is too poorly worded to understand how it results in your example output. If you want an answer, improve the question

Comment: I think you might be trying to say "group with each tuple all the other  tuples that share the same first element or the same last element as the current one"., But if that's the case there should be more than just `(1,2)` and `(3,4)` as keys in your output - please explain why only those two keys appear

Comment: first it will take (1,2) then it will try to make group and include (1,2),(4,2) in it. After it will take (3,4) and include (5,4),(3,8) in group. Now it will go to (1,3) but it is already in some group so it will not take it.. Thats what i wanted

Comment: What happens with duplicate tuples?

Comment: Duplicate tuples should not come twice. It should appear only once,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work

```
a.foldLeft(List[((Int, Int), List[(Int, Int)])]())
  {(acc, t) => if (acc.exists (_._2.contains(t)))
                 acc
               else
                 (t,  a.filter(u => u != t && (u._1 == t._1 || u._2 == t._2)))::acc
  }.toMap 
//> res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[(Int, Int),List[(Int, Int)]] =
// Map((3,4) -> List((5,4), (3,8)),
       (1,2) -> List((1,3), (4,2)))
```

Go over the list. If this tuple is already in our accumulator, do nothing. Otherwise, filter the list for all tuples that are not the current tuple and share either the first or second element with the current one.

Comment: I understand the logic behind this. But I want to understand how foldleft will work in this case. If you have time then kindly explain me the internal working on foldleft here.

Comment: just `a.foldLeft(List[((Int, Int), List[(Int, Int)])]())` part

Comment: That's passing in the starting value of the accumulator. An empty List of tuples, each of which is a (tuple. list of tuples).